# CPP program consuming so much Ram

Tags: c++, macos, ram

One of my simple CPP file is taking so much f memory . Any suggestions? I use a macbook air 2017 model for coding
The code is :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> v;

    int x = 0, y, i;
    while (1) {
        cin >> x;
        if (x == 42) {
            break;
        }
        v.push_back(x);
    }

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
        if (*it < 42) {
            cout << *it << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Here's what I get inside the activity monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y49wS.jpg)

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: What is this reading in? Does that file contain the value `42`? Are you sure it's this code that's causing the issue? This will keep allocating memory without limit, which could be punishing if you're feeding in a large file that is devoid of the value `42`.

Comment: Your code has 5 opening braces `{` but 6 closing `}`. Is this really the code your program is built from? It shouldn't compile at all.

Comment: Did clang format and remove additional closing brace.

Comment: @Awanish taking a photo of a screen (on MacOS) is unacceptable. Just press `CMD-Shift-4` selection cursor will appear, then press `space` and click widow you need to capture.

Comment: Apparently input file has invalid contents and `int` value can't be read. Input stream is in error state, so data are not read and code never encounters value `42`. End result is infinitive loop which eats all memory.

Comment: Other reason input file do not contain value `42`, you reach end of file, stream goes to eror state and .... infinitive loop.

Comment: @MarekR good point, like `while (cin)` could make a world of difference here.

Comment: If no data is input except triggering end-of-file, then you have an infinite loop that continually grows the vector, until memory is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently input file has invalid contents and you do not handle errors well.

**Scenario 1**:
Input has something what can't be read as `int`.

```
1 2 2.0 42 2
```

Here when `2.0` trying to read `int` wyo will get value `2`. In next iteration attempt to read `.0` will fail. `std::cin` is set to error state and any other read attempts are ignored.

**Scenario 2**:
Input do not contain termination value `42`:

```
1 2 3 44 55 10
```

In this case you reach end of file `std::cin` is set to error state and any other read attempts are ignored.

In both cases `x` is never set to value `42` and you have infinitive loop which inserts last successful value read as log there is enough memory. When memory is consumed program terminates with `std::bad_alloc` exception.

To fix it just handle input errors.